# Filter SOQL result by subquery

Tags: soql, relationships

I added Lookup relationship to opportunity, I use it to create Renewal opportunity (N) - (1) Prior opportunity relationship. So Renewal points to the Prior opportunity.

Now I need to create a scheduled batch job for all opportunities without renewals.

I can query all Prior opportunities and their renewals using relationship:

```
SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Opportunities1__r) FROM Opportunity
```

The problem that it returns everything, is there any way to filter result to show only opportunities with `0 Opportunities1__r`?

I tried to use `HAVING` like in real SQL but SOQL doesn't support such constructions.

Answer (score 3):

Normally you would be able to use a [`Left Inner Join`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Left_Inner_Join), but this type of subquery is not supported when joining to the same table (hierarchical relationship). Instead, your best bet is to add a `Number` field and use [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) (or a similar tool) to roll up the child count. Then your query would simply look like:

```
SELECT (SELECT Id FROM Opportunities1__r)
FROM Opportunity
WHERE Child_Count__c > 0
```

---

<s>Yes you sure can. What you are looking for is a [`Left Inner Join`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Left_Inner_Join).</s>

For instance, if your lookup name were `Parent_Opportunity__c`, that would look like:

```
SELECT (SELECT Id FROM Opportunities1__r)
FROM Opportunity
WHERE Id IN (SELECT Parent_Opportunity__c FROM Opportunity)
```

You could also use `HAVING` if you wanted to find parents with multiple children, but you would have to use an *aggregate query* on the child:

```
SELECT Parent_Opportunity__c, count(Id)
FROM Opportunity
WHERE Parent_Opportunity__c != null // <= this clause tells you the record is a child
GROUP BY Parent_Opportunity__c // <= this clause lets you use HAVING
HAVING count(Id) > 1
```

Comment: Yeah, I already tried such queries but it fails with "The inner and outer selects should not be on the same object type"